# Doctxpl doesnt create a new save document

Tags: python, python-docx, docxtpl

While the code runs without issues, I cannot locate the "perro.docx" document (the one with the replaceable variables). It's not in the same folder as my Python file and document template. Additionally, I sometimes encounter an error that states the document template cannot be found, even though it's in the same folder. As a beginner, I'm having difficulty finding a solution to this problem. I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thank you.

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


def Datos_Entrada(mensaje): 
    while True:  
        try: 
            Entrada = int(input(mensaje))
            if Entrada >= 0 :
                return Entrada
            else: 
                print("Valor no Valido")

        except ValueError: 
            print("Valor equivocado")

#Datos Obtenidos por el Usuario 
def Operaciones(): 

    Unidades_Servicios_hechos = Datos_Entrada("Unidades Vendidas/Servicios hechos:  ")
    Ingresos_Entrada = Datos_Entrada("Ingresos:  ")
    Cuentas_PorCobrar = Datos_Entrada("Cuentas Por Cobrar:  ")
    GastosOperativos_Entrada = Datos_Entrada("Gastos Operativos:  ")
    GastosAdminVentas_Entrada = Datos_Entrada("Gastos Admin/Ventas:  ")
    
    #Datos_Obtenidos = [Unidades_Servicios_hechos, Ingresos_Entrada, Cuentas_PorCobrar, GastosOperativos_Entrada, GastosAdminVentas_Entrada]
    #Operacioens sobre los Ingresos 
    
    IngresosPorProducto_Salida = Ingresos_Entrada / Unidades_Servicios_hechos

    #Operaciones sobre los Gastos 
    GastosTotales_Salida = GastosOperativos_Entrada + GastosAdminVentas_Entrada
    GastosPorProducto_Salida = GastosTotales_Salida / Unidades_Servicios_hechos
    

    #Operaciones para sacar datos de las utilidades
    UtilidadesOperativas_Salida = Ingresos_Entrada - GastosOperativos_Entrada
    UtilidadesTotales_Salida = Ingresos_Entrada - GastosTotales_Salida 
    MargenGanancia_Salida = UtilidadesTotales_Salida / Ingresos_Entrada * 100
    UtilidadesPorProducto_Salida = UtilidadesTotales_Salida / Unidades_Servicios_hechos

    return Unidades_Servicios_hechos, Ingresos_Entrada, Cuentas_PorCobrar, GastosOperativos_Entrada, GastosAdminVentas_Entrada, IngresosPorProducto_Salida, GastosPorProducto_Salida, GastosTotales_Salida, UtilidadesOperativas_Salida, UtilidadesTotales_Salida, MargenGanancia_Salida, UtilidadesPorProducto_Salida
Operaciones()
    

#Imprimir los datos Obtenidos 
def Documento():
    Documento_Input = DocxTemplate("C:/Users/980014096/OneDrive/Escritorio/Python/PROYECTOS/Análisis_Periodo/Documento.docx")

    Unidades_Servicios_hechos, Ingresos_Entrada, Cuentas_PorCobrar, GastosOperativos_Entrada, GastosAdminVentas_Entrada, IngresosPorProducto_Salida, GastosPorProducto_Salida, GastosTotales_Salida, UtilidadesOperativas_Salida, UtilidadesTotales_Salida, MargenGanancia_Salida, UtilidadesPorProducto_Salida = Operaciones()

    context = {
        'A': Unidades_Servicios_hechos,
        'B' : Ingresos_Entrada,
        'C' : Cuentas_PorCobrar,
        'D' : GastosOperativos_Entrada,
        'E' : GastosAdminVentas_Entrada,
        'F' : GastosTotales_Salida,
        'G' : IngresosPorProducto_Salida,
        'H' : GastosPorProducto_Salida,
        'I' : UtilidadesOperativas_Salida,
        'J' : UtilidadesTotales_Salida,
        'K' : MargenGanancia_Salida,
        'M' : UtilidadesPorProducto_Salida,
    }    

    Documento_Input.render(context)
    Documento_Input.save("Perro.docx")
    print("El archivo se ha guardado correctamente")
    

print("Lo lograste")
```

I've attempted to move the files to different folders, rename them, and use the exact path, but I'm still encountering issues. When I try to access the documents, I receive an error message stating that the newly saved document cannot be found. This is my first time using this particular library,

Comment: The only function that is called is `Operaciones()`. The document save, `Documento_Input.save("Perro.docx")` is in the function `Documento()` which is never called.

Comment: Yes, i decide to remake my code, i also make a basic GUI, if could give me your opinion on my new code, i´ll be very pleased, thanks for your time. https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/newbie-code-review-income-and-expenses-analysis/608712

Comment: Can you add the error message that you mentioned to your question? Also, the code for rendering the document is in `Operaciones` but it's never called.